# call javascript method inside php code cause parsing error

Tags: javascript, php

I have javascript method

```
function getLocalizedString(lang,key) {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

    var english = {};
    english['categories'] = {'Categories'};

    var arabic = {};
    arabic['categories'] = {'التصنيفات'};

    var french = {};
    french['categories'] = {'Catégories'};

    if (lang === "ar") {
        return arabic[key];
    } else if (lang === "fr") {
        return french[key];     
    } else {
        return english[key];    
    }
}
```

and I am trying to call it inside my php code like this

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="desktopCategories">                            
    <?php 
    $lang = "ar";
    $key = "categories";
    $catg = echo '<script type="text/javascript">getLocalizedString("'.$lang.'","'.$key.'");</script>';
    //$catg = getLocalizedString($lang, 'categories');
    ?>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $catg ; ?></h1>
</div>
```

but it does not work and give me parse error, can anyone advice please ?

Comment: Remove `echo` from `$catg = echo`

Comment: `{'Categories'}` <-- why is there `{` and `}`

Comment: What's the error? Is it being thrown by JS or PHP?

Comment: @EdLucas : Exception - syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Comment: @EdLucas: and sometimes it does not give error, but it does not work

Comment: `$catg = echo` is a syntax error. You cannot assign a language construct to a variable. You probably meant to do `echo $catg =`, but then you also do `echo $catg` a couple of lines down so it's unclear what your intention was.

Comment: This would be explained in the log files generated when you ran the code - learn how to capture and read your logs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading your JavaScript from an external file, you may want to ensure that it's loaded first by wrapping your function call in `window.onload`.

```
$catg = echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function() { getLocalizedString("'.$lang.'","'.$key.'"); };</script>';
```

Comment: I tried it with echo gives error, and without echo it does not show anything

Comment: Are you wrapping your `getLocalizedString()` function in `<script>` tags or including it from an external file?

Comment: Upon review, this is only going to work if your `getLocalizedString()` function performs a `document.write()` instead of returning results. See the answer by @Wizard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "call" Javascript from PHP. JavaScript is client-code and PHP is server-code. Remove the curly braces from the object assignments and call your JS code with `document.write` to display the return value of the function like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getLocalizedString(lang,key) {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

    var english = {};
    english['categories'] = 'Categories'; // <-- removed curly braces

    var arabic = {};
    arabic['categories'] = 'التصنيفات';   // <-- removed curly braces

    var french = {};
    french['categories'] = 'Catégories';  // <-- removed curly braces

    if (lang === "ar") {
        return arabic[key];
    } else if (lang === "fr") {
        return french[key];     
    } else {
        return english[key];    
    }
}
</script>

<div class="row-fluid" id="desktopCategories">                            
    <?php 
    $lang = "ar";
    $key = "categories";
    ?>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write(getLocalizedString('<?php echo $lang; ?>', '<?php echo $key; ?>'));
        </script>
    </h1>
</div>
```